What does it mean to normalize a time series signal against another?
I'm looking at ways to reduce the dimensions of a multivariate data set to a univariate signals. But some preprocessing needs to be done first. Someone mentioned that I should combine the signals by first normalizing the time series in the following way: "normalize the signals A, B, C. Normalize them (i.e., ABC) separately by signal D, and then regenerate normalized values for those three signals (ABC)." Signal D is one that works in positive correlation and is dependent on Signal A, meaning when Signal D is high then expect Signal A is high.
I have no idea what the quoted statement means from an implementation standpoint. Can someone explain this to me and make it make sense? In what scenarios should or would you normalize a signal against another time series? How does that look mathematically?
